# NULL pointer exception disappears when adding a printf statement

Tags: c++, c, yacc

I am a bit lost working with the following piece of code:

```
  T_TERM_LIST term_list = term_list_one($1);
  term_list = term_list_add(term_list, $3);
  T_TERM term_equality = term_app(str_make("="), term_list);  
  T_TERM_LIST term_list_2 = term_list_one(term_equality);
  $$ = term_app(str_make("not"), term_list_2); 
  printf("\n100 \n");
```

My question is regarding the last line, if I leave the printf statement it works as expected else if I remove the printf line I get a null pointer exception, I would like to understad what is ging on there.

As a matter of adding information the datatypes used are typedefs of unsigned and list of unsigned.

In addition The code is embedded into a YACC file which may explain the symbols $n in the shared piece of code code.

Comment: Heisenbug ; There is probably a memory corruption somewhere

Comment: The `printf` is a red herring, hiding your problem by masking some memory error somewhere.

Comment: If you can run this in `valgrind` under Linux / UNIX, that may give you some valuable insight as to where you're corrupting memory.

Comment: Undefined behavior? Stack corruption? Heap corruption? There are many reasons you might get the error. To start with, you should probably run your program in a debugger and see what you can gather for information from it. Combine with tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find memory corruption issues.

Comment: Why don't you remove the printf and step with a debugger to see what's going on? Debugging YACC is a little strange but doable.

Comment: What they said. My guess would be that `printf()` writes over some memory which was zeroed before it was called, thus changing a null pointer into a non-null pointer.  The chances are moderate that you have a pointer into stack memory somewhere, which `valgrind` may not be able to help with.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I am going to use gdb and valgrind to see if I can find out which is the my problem source

Comment: By the way, is it normal that printf statements hide null pointer references? If so, how does it works? Thanks!

Comment: The `printf` probably changed the stack layout of the function, or at least changed the garbage on the stack.  (Ok, `printf` doesn't change the stack layout; rather, the fact there's a call to `printf` might cause the compiler to change the stack layout at compile time.)  It changed the preconditions for the code wherever the real bug is.

Comment: I found out that the code compiled by make clean; make is different of the code compiled by make clean; make debug which adds all the flags for debugging. The results for the former are the expected whereas the null pointer reference is obtained in the later case. So I think we can finish this question by pointing that using valgring and gdb is a good choice in order to solve the problem I posed. Thanks!

Comment: It's always good when asking a question led to you learning how to solve your problems. Debuggers are your friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chux advised me I copy & paste my comment as the answer to my question. Actually it is a kind of lessons learned.

I found out that the code compiled by make clean; make is different of the code compiled by make clean; make debug which adds all the flags for debugging. The results for the former are the expected whereas the null pointer reference is obtained in the later case. So I think we can finish this question by pointing that using valgring and gdb is a good choice in order to solve the problem I posed.

Thanks a lot!